# storing french and german names in database table

Tags: mysql, database, character-encoding

I want to store french names and german names in a table but all the special (exotic) characters will be lost. How to tackle this?

Anz%C3%A8re

Comment: Which database are you using? And which encoding have you set it up to use?

Answer (score 1):

Use a table encoding capable of storing those characters, e.g. UTF-8 or something like this. What database do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, before you enter the names in your UTF-8 database, you need to decode the percent-hex-hex escapes. This can be a bit problematic if you're getting the percent-escaped strings from a HTML form, because browsers will not in general tell you which character encoding they used before percent-coding the bytes. The best strategy to follow may be to check if the bytes are valid UTF-8 and assume iso-8859-1 if (and only if) it isn't.

Comment: Each percent sign is followed by two hex digits. The first hex digit encodes the upper 4 bits of a byte, and the second one encodes the lower 4 bits.

Comment: `urldecode()` does. But I don't know which charset it assumes.